# Graceful shutdown/connection draining on Cloud Foundry: SIGTERM/keep-alive HTTP connections

Tags: http, tcp, load-balancing, cloud-foundry, gorouter

I'm wondering what an application is expected to do with alive, but idle, connections from the router when a SIGTERM has been received. From

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/app-lifecycle.html

> Apps must finish their in-flight jobs within ten seconds of receiving the SIGTERM before CF terminates the app with a SIGKILL. For instance, a web app must finish processing existing requests and **stop accepting new requests**.

(emphasis mine)

It doesn't explicitly say that the router won't attempt to route requests to the application after the SIGTERM. Will it attempt this? And if yes, what does it mean to stop accepting new requests on a pre-existing TCP connection?

What is the complete list of things that an application should do after a SIGTERM to ensure as graceful a shutdown as possible, say, on a scale-down event?

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but you want to do everything in your power to prevent a new request from starting cause you only get a finite amount of time to wrap up before SIGKILL ends your app. I think the docs link you're referencing is a generic way of saying to do this -> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#gracefulstop, but for your web server/framework/stack of choice.

Comment: @DanielMikusa "everything in your power to prevent a new request from starting": this is my question, what is the list of everything? e.g. if the router is configured with keep-alive connections to the backend https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/routing-keepalive.html, should these be closed on SIGTERM?

Comment: If it were me, I would close them on SIGTERM. I wouldn't want any additional requests possibly coming into my app while I'm trying to shutdown. That's just more work that I have to finish within the finite window of time before SIGKILL. Using HTTPD for reference, it mentions `exit immediately if they're not serving anything` and `cease listening on all ports`, which both sound like they would be cleaning up keep-alive connections.

Comment: I wouldn't count on Gorouter to not send new requests during the shutdown period. Even if Diego sends the message to remove the app instance from Gorouter's routing tables before the countdown begins, there's still network latency or the possibility that the NATS message doesn't make it to Gorouter, either of which seem like they could allow traffic to the app instance while it's shutting down. In short, Gorouter probably won't send requests to your app instance while it's shutting down, but I doubt there could be a guarantee that it never will.

Comment: Any way to override 10s default grace time while shut down started in cloud foundry ?